# How do I test a Chrome extension using Cypress?

Tags: google-chrome, cypress

I'm trying to test a Chrome extension using Cypress, but it seems that the Cypress browser doesn't recognize the extension.

my cypress.config.js:

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('before:browser:launch', (browser = {}, launchOptions) => {
        if (browser.family === 'chromium' && browser.name !== 'electron') {
          launchOptions.extensions.push('Users\glend\Downloads\build');
        }

        return launchOptions;
      });
    },
  },
});
```

I tried to download the extension manually in the external browser that Cypress opens, but the extension icon still doesn't open in the test space.